# Magento 2: Add text in system.xml

Tags: magento2, system.xml, magento2.2

Is it possible to have plain text next to the label in system config instead of an input field, something like:

```
<field>
    <label>Hey you</label>
    <plainText>Lorem ipsum...</plainText>
</field>
```

The closest I can get is using a label, but thats looks bad when I have more than 4 words in it. This is what it should look like:

[image: Plain text in system config]

Comment: U can use `<comment>`. What is point of giving label as value?

Comment: What you want to show as text only?

Comment: When I use `<comment>` im getting an inputfield. I want display a small note so that users can read that before they submit a file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**system.xml**

```
<field id="test" translate="label" type="label" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
    <label>Hey you!</label>
</field>
```

**config.xml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <section>
            <group>
                <test>Your values here</test>
            </group>
        </section>
    </default>
</config>
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: I cant upvote because I dont have 15 rep yet

Answer (score 3):

I also wanted to add custom text in store configuration and found below simple way to add custom text:

```
<field id="test" translate="label" type="label" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>NOTE: </label>
    <comment>Your Custom TEXT Here...</comment>
</field>
```

Hope will be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

**system.xml**

```
<field id="test" type="label">
    <label>Test</label>
</field>
```

in **config.xml** define it's value

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <groupname>
            <settings>
                <test>values</test>
            </settings>
        </groupname>
    </default>
</config>
```

Use `CDATA[]` if neeed